# ¿ Cómo transformar un string a una lista de string en haskell

Tags: haskell

tengo esta cadena `"la luna,el sol,a,b,c"` y quiero convertirla a

> ["la luna","el sol","a","b","c"] sin usar librerías

¿ Cómo puedo hacer? Tengo este código que me devuelve `"la luna,el sol,a,b,c"` pero deseo convertirlo en una lista de `string`

```
archivo <- readFile "MAPA.txt"
nuevoarchivo <- return(lines archivo)
cadena <- return(limpiarlista $ head nuevoarchivo)
print cadena

limpiarlista :: String -> String
limpiarlista cadena = [x| x <- cadena, not (x `elem` "[]")]
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Un modo de hacerlo sin librerías extras:

```
split :: String -> [String]
split "" = []
split xs = ys : (split . drop 1) zs
   where (ys, zs) = span (/=',') xs
```

Answer (score 1):

Existe el paquete split, que no pertenece a la instalación base de Haskell, pero puedes instalar así:

```
cabal install split
```

para usarlo, simplemente importa el módulo Data.List.Split y utiliza la función splitOn.

```
import Data.List.Split
splitOn "," lista
```

Si lo quieres hacersin librerías extra, puedes modificar la función `words` del Prelude para que separe por una coma en lugar de por espacios.

```
wordsComa   :: String -> [String]
wordsComa s =  case dropWhile (==',') s of
                          "" -> []
                          s' -> w : wordss s''
                                where (w, s'') = break (==',') s'
```